# How to fix Run time errorr 3067 Query input

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to import an excel sheet on the backend of my split database but I am having complications with this error that states I do not have any  queries as an input which I believe I have my query formatted wrong but I have no idea how to fix it. Please advise.

```vb
Dim sDBFile AS String 
Dim sXLSFILE AS String 
Dim sSheet AS String 
Dim sTableName As String

sSheet1 = "BJS Commit"
sTableName1 = "tblUpdateBJS Commit"
  CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT * INTO [;DATABA-SE=" & _
  sDBFile & ";]." & sTableName1 & _
  "FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=" & _
  sXLSFile & ";].[" & sSheet1 & "$];", dbFailOnError
```

Comment: What is the actual language of the error? Also put `print "SELECT * INTO [;DATABA-SE=" &  sDBFile & ";]." & sTableName1 & "FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=" & sXLSFile & ";].[" & sSheet1 & "$];"` in the Immediate pane and enter the result in your question above.

Comment: Run time error 3067 Query input must contain at last one table or query

Comment: Are you familiar with the use of the Immediate window? Actually seeing the final Select statement will help significantly in troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: With the VBE open, click CTRL-g...then paste in the print statement from above and hit enter after you execute the line that defines sTableName1.

Comment: You need a space before the `FROM` clause.

Comment: SELECT * [;DATABASE=;] .FROM [Excel 12.0 ;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=;].[$];

Comment: output from the immediate window

Comment: You need to execute the print statement while the code is running.

Comment: The table and sheet names would appear in your statement if they are defined (as you step through your code)

Comment: Also, you've dimmed `sDBFile` and `sXLSFILE` but at no point have you assigned anything to those variables.

Comment: I have the pathway set just  I missed including that portion once I made this post